# Flutter: Scroll to next page when reached end of a nested horizontal scroll

Tags: flutter

We are currently building an app in Flutter that has a sequence of pages which you can swipe between, and inside each page we have a horizontal scroll.

We want it so that once you have reached the end of the horizontal scroll, it should be possible to scroll/swipe to next page by scrolling further inside the horizontal scroll.

Here is a video showing the desired behaviour:
https://vimeo.com/358643279

We have a problem with our current implementation which is shown below. 
It includes a `PageView` for each page and inside each page we have a `ListView` for the horizontal scroll.

Once we hit the end of the horizontal scroll, it does not allow you to scroll to the next page by scrolling further.

In order to scroll to the next page, you must make a scrolling gesture outside of the horizontal scroll in order for it to register which is not ideal.

Here is a minimal example which you should be able to copy and paste.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'ScrollingDemo',
        home: PageView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
          Page(title: "Page 1"),
          Page(title: "Page 2")
        ]));
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  Page({@required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listView = ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildContainer(1),
        _buildContainer(2),
        _buildContainer(3),
        _buildContainer(4),
        _buildContainer(5)
      ],
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(title),
        Container(height: 200, width: 500, child: listView)
      ],
    );
  }

  Container _buildContainer(int index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to how scrolling works.  You have two horizontal scrolling widgets with one on top of the other (the ListView on top of the PageView) thus the ListView is preventing scroll effects from reaching the PageView.  You can work around this using `ScrollController`s and a `PageController`.  Add separate ScrollControllers to the ListView and listen for scroll events in those controllers then set the page of the PageController on the PageView accordingly.

```
_scrollListener() async {
    ScrollPosition position = _controller.position;
    if (_controller.offset == position.maxScrollExtent) {
      widget.pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
    } else if (_controller.offset == position.minScrollExtent) {
      widget.pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
    }
  }
```

Note that you'll have to switch to a StatefulWidget Page class to achieve this as well but that is very simple to do.  This code should do the trick:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'ScrollingDemo',
        home: PageView(controller: _pageController, scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
          Page(
            title: "Page 1",
            pageController: _pageController,
          ),
          Page(title: "Page 2", pageController: _pageController)
        ]));
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final PageController pageController;
  final String title;
  Page({@required this.title, @required this.pageController});

  @override
  PageState createState() {
    return PageState();
  }
}

class PageState extends State<Page> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  _scrollListener() async {
    ScrollPosition position = _controller.position;
    if (_controller.offset == position.maxScrollExtent) {
      widget.pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
    } else if (_controller.offset == position.minScrollExtent) {
      widget.pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listView = ListView(
      controller: _controller,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[_buildContainer(1), _buildContainer(2), _buildContainer(3), _buildContainer(4), _buildContainer(5)],
    );

    return Column(
      children: [Text(widget.title), Container(height: 200, width: 500, child: listView)],
    );
  }

  Container _buildContainer(int index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```